# How to post form-data IFormFile to API from Controller?

Tags: file, asp.net-core, iformfile

received null  in api IFormFile.

Javascript:

```
var archivo = _('inputCargar').files[0];        
const form = new FormData();
form.append("files", archivo);
const config = {
headers: {
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}}     
    await axios.post(`${data.urlUtil}Insert_FileAzure`, form, config);
```

The form file arrive to the controller but cant arrive to the api
Controller in Front:

```
   public async Task<JsonResult> Insert_FileAzure([FromForm]  ICollection<IFormFile> files)
        {
           
            var result = await _apiUtil.PostAsync<ICollection<IFormFile>> ("File/UploadAzure", files);
            return Json(result);
        }
```

API:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<RespuestaUpload>> UploadAzure([FromForm(Name = "files")] ICollection<IFormFile> files)
{
  if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
    return Content("file not selected");
  var respuestaUpload = await _utiles.UploadFilesAzure(files);
  return Ok(respuestaUpload);
}
```

Comment: Could be anything. Elaborate on the post (javascript) part - what you've tried so far and what did and what did not work.

Comment: Can you show us the FileController?

Comment: The first code is the javascript, second controller in the same project FRONT and third is the api in another project, the problem is the IFormFile arrive to the controller but in the API is null.

Comment: So, the request can enter the `UploadAzure` function, only didn't receive the files, right? If so, can you show the `PostAsync` function in `_apiUtil`

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5eO7ZK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MultipartFormDataContent` as httpContent like below:

```
var Client = new HttpClient();
var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
foreach (IFormFile file in files)
{
    byte[] fileData;
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        fileData = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.OpenReadStream().Length);
    }
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileData);
    multipartFormDataContent.Add(fileContent, "files", file.FileName);
}

var response = await Client.PostAsync(requestUrl, multipartFormDataContent);
```

Comment: This solution solve my problem, i make modification in my _apiutil, but your code work perfectly